# What's the best way to display folder photos with their names and filter in JavaFX?

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I have been working on a program for a long time, the only confusing part to me is how to display photos from a certain folder into a scene(or a list) with the file names displayed somewhere and a filter available to filter file names, I tried many ways for a long time, the most way I tried was a ListView with names displayed and Images and I was also able to add imageview and zoom in and out when ever an image clicked as shown here:

[image]

But this one does not have a filter (which I need) and every time I try to research for a way to add a filter it seems too complicated given that I have many lines on code in this Listview and it's hard to modify it to add a filter.
I thought about discarding this listview and start over, but Listviews are  complicated to implement and I thought there maybe another way to do this.

I realize that since i invested too much time doing this Listview with images, the sane thing to do is not start over but try to add a filter to my existing listview and I am done, but too many lines of codes are involved and it would be discouraging to find them one by one in order to add the filter.

I wanted to get opinions from JavaFX professionals before I do anything, I didn't want to keep thinking about this by my own.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use a ControlsFX [GridView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) for the image display with a grid cell consisting of as a Label with an ImageView for the graphic and image name for the text and a [FilteredList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) to limit the display.

Comment: There is no "best" way to do this (making the question too broad to answer as currently asked).  There are many ways to display images.  The most flexible is to allow the user to choose a display option (e.g. list, grid, carousel).  See for example the [OS X Finder options](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22173?locale=en_US), the "Icon" view would be a GridView, the "List" view would be a TableView, the "Cover Flow" view would be a [Carousel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Mb15bOwIyE).